# Rxjs Observable : subscribe to different values with one API call

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a CRUD API where the get on the entity returns both the list and the total number of items for the current filter configuration.

For example : `GET /posts`

```
{
    "items": [
        {
             "id": 1,
             "title": "post title 1"
        }
        ...
    ],
    "total": 9
}
```

How can I create an observable where the HTTP query is executed only one time but where I can subscribe to either the total value or the items list ?

I am in an Angular2 context with typescript.

I first tried this and it worked :

```
this.http.get('/api/posts').map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
  var items = data.items
  var total = data.total
});
```

But I don't like this as I cannot use my interface for the Post entity (or I must defined an interface like that `{items: Post, total: number}` this is not really graceful). What I would like to do is something like this :

```
this.myPostService.totalObservable.subscribe(total => this.total = total)
this.myPostService.itemsObservable.subscribe(items => this.items = items)
```

But without triggering 2 queries.

I looked into this blog post : https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services but I don't like the fact that you first subscribe and then call the list() method to load the list.

Comment: Hi @paulpdaniels. I have updated my question with some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need it to run once you can cache the value directly:

```
var source = this.http.get('/api/posts').map(response => response.json()).publishLast();

//unsubscribe from this when you are done
var subscription = source.connect();
```

Then you can expose the two sources as:

```
var totalObservable = source.pluck('total');
var itemsObservable = source.pluck('items');
```

If on the other hand you need to call these Observables multiple times, then I would recommend that you wrap the `get` in a triggering Observable and cache:

```
var source = sourceTrigger
  .startWith(0) //Optionally initialize with a starting value
  //This ensures that only the latest event is in flight.
  .flatMapLatest(() => this.http.get('/api/posts'), (_, resp) => resp.json())
  .cache(1);

//Again expose these items using `pluck`
var totalObservable = source.pluck('total');
var itemsObservable = source.pluck('items');
```

In the second case the `sourceTrigger` would be an `Observable` that might be connected to a button event, so that each button click triggers a new request.

Comment: Your second solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I didn't know the `pluck` method and couldn't find it in the doc.

Comment: I had to use `share` on the source to prevent the queries being emitted 2 times.

Comment: `cache` is just `share` + `replay` so they should function the same.